# Why are recursive methods usually static in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, static

I'm reviewing recursion these days and found out that a lot of Java recursive method samples are static. Can somebody explain why?

My guess is that they want to save memory, since logically a "parent" recursive method is staying dumb as long as its children recursive method is running and doesn't return anything yet.

Also please check if the following guess is right:

The static recursive method is running on the same thread while a non-static one may run on separate threads, is this correct or doesn't make any sense?

Comment: _The static recursive method is running on the same thread while a non-static one may run on separate threads, is this correct or doesn't make any sense?_ It is absolutely incorrect. You have a few concepts here that I think you need to review individually before you proceed. Understand what the different is between a `static` method and an instance method. Understand what recursion is. If you want, understand what threads are, but that's unrelated.

Comment: 'A lot' isn't the same thing as 'usually'. Baseless generalization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because a recursive method/algorithm is generally controlled solely by its parameters and not by instance variables.

Any method that does not rely on instance variables can (and probably should) be made `static`.

Comment: That last comment is just plain wrong in my opinion. The decision to make a method static depends on whether it's semantically a method of the type or the specific instance. Just because the current implementation doesn't depend on the instance doesn't mean it never will – but later on it'll be a breaking API change.

Comment: @IngoBürk - Good point - but I would disagree on the *just plain wrong*. I used the word *can* deliberately. It is easier to move a static method into the instance than it is to move it out so I go for simplicity at the outset when possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are right they are static because they have a global scope and they make efficient memory management. If we declare something as static then they will not same for each objects i.e. every object will not have its own copy of the variable and methods.