# Does a recursive method ever take a class attribute/data filed as parameter?

Tags: java, recursion, parameters, static

This question arose in my mind from the following comment on Stack Overflow:

> Q: Why is recursive method usually static in Java?
>
> Ans:  Because a recursive method/algorithm is generally controlled
>   solely by it's parameters and not by instance variables.Any method
>   that does not rely on instance variables can (and probably should) be
>   made static.

There are plenty other methods that can be defined in a class that are not controlled by the instances but rather method parameter. One simple example would be when an object that is created from no-arg constructor calls a parametarized method, the method is really controlled by the parameters.

Then I found only one possible exception: If the parameters in a method also happen to be class attributes, then the method cannot be static because the attributes are changed according to each instance. That means recursive method never takes parameters that are class attributes.

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Please give me an example if I'm correct. The Stack Overflow post that I'm quoting is [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127667/why-is-recursive-method-usually-static-in-java)

Comment: It's not parameters which warrant a static method, it's instance variables. If the method in any way gets or sets instance variables, it cannot be static. Even an object initialized with the default constructor has instance variables which could be used in an instance method.

Comment: The comment you quote saying that if it doesn't rely on instance variables it should be made static is utterly wrong. Please don't believe it.

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method doesn't reference any instance variables or methods, then it could be made static. That doesn't mean it should be made static (but that's not really in the scope of this question). Applying that logic to recursive methods is making some perhaps common assumptions, but isn't necessarily correct unto itself.

A common recursive operation is iterating over files, something like:

```
doForEveryFile(File root)
{
  if (root.isFile()) do_something_with_that_file(root);
  else if (root.isDirectory())
  {
     for (File next_file : root.listFiles()) doForEveryFile(next_file);
  }
}
```

But in that case, if do_something_with_that_file() is an instance method, then the recursive method still couldn't be static. If it is static, then this could be a static recursive method. So even with this simple case, it should be clear that recursion itself isn't a clear driver for likelihood of being static or not.

We could also write a math case, version one, static:

```
// sum all numbers from one to our given value
class StaticRecursive {
  public static int sumTo(int max) { return recursiveSum(); }
  private static int recursiveSum(int currentSum, int currentValue, int max)
  {
    if (currentValue == max) return currentSum;
    else return recursiveSum(currentSum + currentValue, currentValue + 1, max);
  }
}
```

That's entirely static. I could instead write it like:

```
class InstanceRecursive {
  private int max;
  private int sum;
  public int sumTo(int max) {
    this.max = max;
    this.sum = 0;
    return recursiveSum(0);
  }
  public void recursiveSum(int currentValue)
  {
    if (currentValue == this.max) return;
    else {
      sum += currentValue;
      recursiveSum(currentValue + 1);
    }
  }
```

Those two basically do the same thing, one without instance variables, one with instance variables. What's the difference? Not much. The instance version will use less stack space, but that's about it.

Anyway, in summary, static has to do with instance variable/method references (if none, it could be static). Philosophically, if a method could be static, why is it part of that class? Recursion might be an interesting case to consider, but there's nothing special or specific about a recursive method as to whether or not it would be static.